# Transistor to switch 10A 250V

Tags: transistors

Is there a transistor to switch 250V power supply to control lights & fans?
I know there are relays to do this work but I need a transistor solution..

Comment: Unfortunately, recommendations for specific components are off-topic in this forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please investigate solid-state relays; they are opto-coupled "transistor-relays".

Such as:
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10636

Comment: Exactly this is what I was looking for Thankyou

Comment: I don't believe this is an issue for the OP, since he mentioned controlling lights and fans, but since the SSR you linked to uses a triac, it can only be used for AC.  There are also SSRs that use MOSFETS that can switch DC loads.